# Cannot declare a variable named 'yn' in Arduino using the SODAQ Autonomo

Tags: arduino

When using the SODAQ Autonomo board in Arduino I wanted to declare a variable (integer) with the name 'yn'. Declaring this variable leads to the following error:

```
'int yn' redeclared as different kind of symbol
```

I found that changing the SODAQ Autonomo board to another board fixed this error.

Nevertheless, I would like to find out why this error is popping up. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many math libraries include Bessel functions, which are called, `j0`, `j1`, `jn`, and `y0`, `y1`, `yn`, but the standard AVR `math.h` doesn't have them. Maybe the support files for that Autonomo board define them?